# Get the id of the only remaining selected row jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

I have this scenario (numbers given for example):

At the beginning I select the first row. 
Then I select the fifth row. After that I unselect the fifth row .
How can I obtain the id of the first row (that is the Id of the only selected row remaining)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

jqGrid support selection of multiple rows at once if you use `multiselect: true` option. You can get the array of ids of all selected rows by using

```js
var selIds = $("#gridid").jqGrid("getGridParam", "selarrrow");
```

Additionally to `selarrrow` there are exist `selrow` which holds *the id of the last* selected row. You don't wrote which fork of jqGrid you use and in which version. So it could be some differences in the value returned in `selrow`. The most safe would be to get `selarrrow` parameter like in the code above. If will the the array with one elements in the scenario described in your example and `selIds[0]` will be the first (and the only) selected row.